# How to categorize a bunch of numbers in Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in excel containing a bunch of numbers. I want to categorize them in some groups according to their ranges. For example, group 1 : 300-500 , group 3: 500-700 , ... and count the members of each group.

Does anybody have an idea?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways.  For example *(300-500)*:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A20>299)*(A1:A20<501))
```

[image]

*(similar for the other groups)*
**Make sure groups do not overlap:**
Next group *(501-700)*:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A20>500)*(A1:A20<701))
```